# Find unknown method or keyword in VBE

Tags: vba, excel

In a code I didn't write, there is this line, 
not in a module but where you can put code for each sheet (i don't know the name) :

`ActiveSheet.Sort_Existing.value = True`

First i was thinking it was the name of a range but it's not the case and the variable is not declared everywhere !

So is it just a variable you can set up like this ?

Comment: Did you try to search in the whole project for `Sort_Existing`? Press F2 in VBE for Object Explorer and search for `Sort_Existing`, you might found some info... And it's a sheet's module, generally use to handle sheet's events. So at least `ActiveSheet` should be `Me` (talking about the object you're in).

Comment: Thanks it was a CheckBox i didnt see !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ActiveSheet` points to the currently active sheet in the currently active workbook

and `Sort_Existing` most probably is the name of an `ActiveX` `CheckBox` control in that sheet

so:

- if you want to point to some other worksheet in the currently active workbook you may use:

  ```
  Worksheets("myOtherWorksheetName").Sort_Existing.value = True
  ```

  provided `Sort_Existing` means something for that worksheet, like for instance the name of an `ActiveX` `CheckBox` control in that sheet
- if you want to point to some other `CheckBox` control in the currently active sheet of the currently active workbook you may use:

  ```
  ActiveSheet.MyOtherCheckBoxName.value = True
  ```

  with `MyOtherCheckBoxName` being a valid name of any `ActiveX` `CheckBox` control in the *Active* sheet

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! My question was more precisely "how do i know to what `Sort_Existing` refers ?"

Comment: see edited answer: it most probably is the name of a `CheckBox` control in the sheet whose code pane you're actually looking at

Answer (score 3):

To find an unknown Keywords, Procedure, or something else :

1. Try to search (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>) in the whole **Project**
2. Press <kbd>F2</kbd> in VBE for **Object Explorer** and search for it,
   you'll find some very useful info in there, you can browse between classes, objects, methods, ...

And you are talking about a sheet's module.
It's generally use to handle sheet's events. 
So at least `ActiveSheet` should be `Me` (talking about the object you're in)